# Set margin if enough space

Tags: html, css, margin

I have 1 container (`width:800px`) in my body.

The container should have a margin to one side if there is enough space (screen width > (800px + margin)) but no margin if the screenwidth <= 800px.

**How?**

Update - some code:

```
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #container {
            display: block;
            float: right;
            width: 800px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #474747;
            margin-right: 100px;
        }
    </style>


<body>
    <div id="container">TODO write content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `float:right` doesn't help?

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?  It seems like this should work more or less automatically to me depending on what the margin is

Comment: when I resize my window, the margin should decrease to zero at screen width = container width. The container is `position: absolute` but I might change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mediaqueries:

```
#container {
  width: 800px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 820px) {
   #container {
      margin-left: 20px;
   }
}
```

e.g if your margin is `20px` just check for a `800+20`px as a min-width

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries and for oldest browser (IE<=8) there are javascript libraries able to emulate the same behaviour.